# Проблемма с cheerio и масивом

Tags: javascript, node.js, cheerio

У меня есть функция которая в зависимости от параметров парсит или  названия или цены или url . Последнее и первое отлично работает . Цены вообще не хочет парсить хотя вроде всё норм сделано .
Вот код:

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const cheerio   = require('cheerio');

async function getPageContent(url){
    try {
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch()
        const page = await browser.newPage()
        await page.goto(url)
        const content = await page.content()
        await browser.close();
        //console.log(content);
        return content;
    }catch (error){
        throw error
    }
}
async function getElements($, sel, options){
    try {
        let elements = [];
        let element
        //проходимся по всем элементам масива по селектору(sel)
        $(sel).each((idx, elem) =>{
            if(options.isParent){
                element = $(elem).parent()
            }
            else {
                element = $(elem)
            }
            if(options.elType === 'title'){
                let title = element.text()
                let obj = {
                    id: idx,
                    title: title,
                }
                elements.push(obj);
            }
            if(options.elType === 'price'){
                let price = element.text();
                //Это на случай пробелов и лишних символов в строчке
                price = price.split(" ").join('')
                price = price.split("\n").join('')
                if(price === '-' || price === ''){
                    price = 'Нет в продаже'
                }
                //Если валюта рубли то добовляем "руб"
                if(options.valute === 'руб'){
                    if(price !== 'Нет в продаже'){
                        price = `${price} руб`
                        let obj = {
                            id: idx,
                            price: price,
                        }
                        elements.push(obj);
                    }else{
                        let obj = {
                            id: idx,
                            price: price,
                        }
                        elements.push(obj);
                    }
                }
            }
            if(options.elType === 'url'){
                let obj;
                let url = element.attr('href')
                if(!url.startsWith(options.siteURL)){
                    obj = {
                        id: idx,
                        url: `${options.siteURL}${url}`,
                    }
                }
                else{
                    obj = {
                        id: idx,
                        url: url,
                    }
                }
                elements.push(obj);
            }
        })
        return elements;
        //console.log(elements)
    }catch (error){
        console.log(error);
    }
}
async function getBooks(name,url,opts){
    try{
        const content = await getPageContent(`${url}${name}`);
        const $ = cheerio.load(content);
        let books = '';
        let titles  = await getElements($, opts.titleOpts.sel, opts.titleOpts)
        let prices  = await getElements($, opts.priceOpts.sel, opts.priceOpts)
        for(let i = 0; i < titles.length - 1; i++){
            books = `${books}|${titles[i].id + 1}| ${titles[i].title} - ${prices[i].price} \n`
        }
        console.log(books)
        return(books)
    }catch (err){
        console.error(err)
    }
}
async function test(name) {
    try {
        const url = "https://librarius.md/ru/search?search="
        const librOpts = {
            titleOpts: {
                elType: 'title',
                sel: '.card-title'
            },
            priceOpts: {
                elType: 'price',
                sel: '.card-price',
                valute: 'лей'
            }
        }
        let books = await getBooks(name, url, librOpts)
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err)
    }
}
test('Ведьмак')
```

Прекол в том что  в консоль выводится ошибка о том что prices[i].price undefined . Я проверял код и по идее такого не может быть .
Помогите пожалуйста я не могу найти свою ошибку

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ты получаешь пустой список цен из-за того, что "цену" в "список" ты добавляешь только если валюта - рубль.

Вот в этот условный оператор ты можешь войти только если `options.valute === 'руб'`, а в аргументах передаётся `лей`:

```
if (options.valute === 'руб') {
  if (price !== 'Нет в продаже') {
    ...
    elements.push(obj);
  } else {
    ...
    elements.push(obj);
  }
}
```

```
priceOpts: {
  elType: 'price',
  sel: '.card-price',
  valute: 'лей'
}
```

---

Должно быть примерно так:

```
    if (options.elType === 'price') {
      let price = element.text()?.replace(/\s/g, '');
      if (price === '-' || price === '') {
        price = 'Нет в продаже';
      } else if (options.valute === 'руб') {
        price = `${price} руб`;
      }
      elements.push({ id: idx, price });
    }
```

Comment: а понял . Тупанул однако жёстко . Спасибо огромное